# Retrieve a unique permanent machine(Laptop/Computer) ID using java

Tags: java, windows, unique

I have developed a software in **JAVA** in which I need to register user machine in my database.

Each user machine must be unique, if user login from another machine it should be detected.

For this I have use **wmic** commands to get ProcessorId and Baseboard SerialNumber.

I am appending baseboard serial number to processorId for more uniqueness.
But the problem is I am getting same ProcessorId+SerialNumber for 2 different machines.
For Eg : Machine 1 = abcd-123
Machine 2  = abcd-123

Also Baseboard serial number giving output like "**N/A**", "**Unknown**", "**To be field by O.E.M**".

I have thought of **wmic csproduct get UUID** which gives Mother board UUID,
 but I am afraid of duplicity of the same, as many user has been already registered their machines and using the software.

**Situation**
 User-1 already registered with machine text abcd-123 (processorId-basebord Sr No) 
Now User-2 login to the system for very first time with different machine 
having the same machine text i.e abcd-123 
At the time of machine validation at server, User-2's machine shown as already registered so User-2 cannot proceed.

Please help me solving the problem.

Comment: If this application can connect to internet, why don't you just have some auto_increment based database table, so every time a new user registers, you get a unique ID.

Comment: No, I need a single machine to be registered against only a single user.

Comment: Using Java [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) would be an excellent choice.

Comment: Motherboard UUID can be duplicate : https://www.nextofwindows.com/the-best-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-windows-machine

Comment: You should edit your question to answer the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)", as they will help you decide how best to generate unique identifiers.  For instance, a random UUID (e.g., via the `randomUUID` method of `java.util.UUID`) is appropriate if you have an easy way to check IDs for uniqueness or if you can tolerate the risk of duplicate IDs.

Comment: Also, although "[Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) is Android-specific, some of the advice given there may apply to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I used user machine uuid by using wmic command. 
**wmic csproduct get uuid** 
This is unique for every motherboard. 
IF UUID not available I used processorId + MobileNo

CURRENTLY THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

Use UUIDs.

https://www.quora.com/Has-there-ever-been-a-UUID-collision

It should never collide if you do it right, considering bigger services than yours use it with no problem.

Comment: This UUID is the one our program can generate. I want a UUID of motherboard.

Comment: Why? If you don’t tell us all the requirements we can’t really help you.

Comment: Bcoz we need to uniquely identify a user machine, not only user. **_I want to maintain a machine registered against a single user so that if a machine is already registered by a user , other user can not use the same machine (laptop)._** 
If we genertae UUID using **UUID.randomUUID()** in java, we cannot know from which machine this UUID id generated, this was the main issue.